# Camel Stopping With No Apparent Reason

Tags: apache-camel

I have a bean producer and a bean consumer, used in a single route. The producer is spawned via a thread and listens for data on an hazelcast queue (it could be anything else, even randomly generated data locally I believe).

The data are sent to a seda endpoint, to ensure concurrency.
The consumer gets data and forwards it to another hazelcast queue. But again it could be anything else.

It works well but after a while, Camel shuts down and I can't find why.

Here are some of the messages I see:

Processing a lot of data...

```
[                          main] MainSupport                    INFO  Apache Camel 2.10.3 stopping
[                          main] DefaultCamelContext            INFO  Apache Camel 2.10.3 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutting down
[                          main] DefaultShutdownStrategy        INFO  Starting to graceful shutdown 1 routes (timeout 300 seconds)
[el-1) thread #2 - ShutdownTask] DefaultShutdownStrategy        INFO  Waiting as there are still 1 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 300 seconds.
```

then processing still during 300 seconds and stopping.

Here some of the code:

Producer:

```
   public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            IRequest service = ProxyHelper.createProxy(context.getEndpoint("seda:echo"), IRequest.class);

            BlockingQueue<Request> q = client.getQueue(MainApp.sQueueReceive);

            while(true)
            {
                Request request;
                request = q.take();
                // no response awaited
                service.request(request);
            }
        }
```

Consumer:

```
   public void onMessage(Request request)
    {
        nb_forwarded++;
        BlockingQueue<Request> q = MainApp.client.getQueue(MainApp.sQueueForward);
        try
        {
            q.put(request);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            exit(2);  --> it does not happen
        }
```

And finally, the route:

```
from("seda:echo")
.setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOnly)
.bean(new HazelcastForwarder(), "onMessage");
```

It's in InOnly as no response is awaited from the producer, it is just a forward.

So why Camel is stopping. There is no message appart from those saying that it is stopping. Is there such a default behaviour in Camel. In which cases?

Thanks!

Comment: usually means you should feed it

Comment: @thang actually it is continually fed as I am performing a performance/endurance test

Comment: oh, then you should give it some water

Comment: @thang this, I can't find some! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable DEBUG or Trace logging to reveil the true reason why camel is stopping. It can be that the enclosing container is stopping (if you are running camel inside something) or similar.

Comment: The process was just ending. I did a Sleep which I thought was really long, but it was not the case!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similar issue, where Camel Context is closing immediately after starting the process. I am posting here so that it would also help others with similar issue.

In my case, I am using Spring for loading the Camel context using '**FileSystemXmlApplicationContext**' and instantiating it with in try block,

```
try(AbstractXmlApplicationContext appContext = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(camelContextPath)) {

}
```

as my Eclipse was complaining about Resource leak. So, as soon as the call was coming out of the try/catch it was closing the Spring context, which again closing the Camel Context.

To fix the issue need to initialize Spring context out side the try block.

```
AbstractXmlApplicationContext appContext = null;
try {
    appContext = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(camelContextPath);

}
```